# How do I create a HttpOrigin for Cloudfront to use a Lambda function url?

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront, aws-cdk

Trying to setup a `Cloudfront` behaviour to use a [Lambda function url](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-urls.html) with code like this:

```ts
    this.distribution = new Distribution(this, id + "Distro", {
      comment: id + "Distro",
      defaultBehavior: {
        origin: new S3Origin(s3Site),
        viewerProtocolPolicy: ViewerProtocolPolicy.REDIRECT_TO_HTTPS,
      },
      additionalBehaviors: {
        [`api-prd-v2/*`]: {
          compress: true,
          originRequestPolicy: originRequestPolicy,
          origin: new HttpOrigin(functionUrl.url, {
            protocolPolicy: OriginProtocolPolicy.HTTPS_ONLY,
            originSslProtocols: [OriginSslPolicy.TLS_V1_2],
          }),
          allowedMethods: AllowedMethods.ALLOW_ALL,
          viewerProtocolPolicy: ViewerProtocolPolicy.HTTPS_ONLY,
          cachePolicy: apiCachePolicy,
        },
```

The `functionUrl` object is created in a different stack and passed in to the `cloudformation` stack, the definition looks like:

```ts
    this.functionUrl = new FunctionUrl(this, 'LambdaApiUrl', {
      function: this.lambdaFunction,
      authType: FunctionUrlAuthType.NONE,
      cors: {
        allowedOrigins: ["*"],
        allowedMethods: [HttpMethod.GET, HttpMethod.POST],
        allowCredentials: true,
        maxAge: Duration.minutes(1)
      }
    });
```

The above code fails because "The parameter origin name cannot contain a colon".
Presumably, this is because `functionUrl.url` evaluates to something like `https://xxx.lambda-url.ap-southeast-2.on.aws/` (note the `https://`) whereas the `HttpOrigin` parameter should just be the domain name like `xxx.lambda-url.ap-southeast-2.on.aws`.

I can't just write code to hack the url up though (i.e. `functionUrl.url.replace("https://", "")`) because when my code executes, the value or the `url` property is a token like `${Token[TOKEN.350]}`.

The function url is working properly: if I hard-code the `HttpOrigin` to the function url's value (i.e. like `xxx.lambda-url.ap-southeast-2.on.aws`) - it works fine.

How do I use CDK code to setup the reference from Cloudfront to the function url?

I'm using `aws-cdk` version 2.21.1.

---

There is an open issue to add support: https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/20090

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [CloudFormation Intrinsic Functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.Fn.html) to parse the url string:

```js
cdk.Fn.select(2, cdk.Fn.split('/', functionUrl.url));

// -> 7w3ryzihloepxxxxxxxapzpagi0ojzwo.lambda-url.us-east-1.on.aws
```